# How to conditionally replace a capture group in regex

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have a string that ends with 4 possible codes that I need to replace with 3 possible codes.
eg,

```
abc.A => abc A code
abc.B => abc B code
abc.C => abc C code
abc.D => abc C code
```

While it's easy enough to get the suffix code into a capture group, I'm wondering how to do a replace such that if the group == "D", replace with "C", else replace with captured group.

The basic subgroup replace pattern:

```
(?<word>\w{3})\.(?<sub>[A-Z]+)
```

The substitution:

```
${word} ${sub} code
```

I'm using c#, but since both the pattern and replace string are read in from a database and replaced (see following) I can't just do it in code:

```
Regex.Replace(mystring, pattern, replaceStr);
```

Where mystring is one of abc.A, abc.B, etc.

Comment: If you just need to replace `abc.D` and keep others intact, why not use `(\w{3}\.)D\b` and replace with `$1 C code`? Please explain what you are doing and add the language tag.

Comment: I can do that, but since my actual case requires many sets of regex it essentially doubles my workload, so I'm looking for a solution that covers all cases.

Comment: Have you looked at using [the `MatchEvaluator` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I need it all to be within the pattern and replace strings.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Right, .NET regex does not support conditional replacement patterns. Boost, PCRE2 and JGSoft do.

Comment: Well. Darn. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Do you know of an online emulator that supports `PCRE2` ?

Comment: @Jan Nio idea, [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/pcre.html) claims to have the library support, but I have never used it.

Comment: What is the reason for the requirement not to use a MatchEvaluator? Does it have to get the replacement string from config or something? Writing your own code to do this based on some kind of simple string format shouldn't be prohibitive.